# Can I keep results with Strife while I'm Compromised if my teammates grant me assistance and take Strife for me?

Tags: l5r, helping, l5r-5e, strife

I'll be directing a game of L5R for the first time and I have some questions about Strife at L5R 5e (the one by Fantasy Flight Games). I might have missed the answers in the core rulebook as I've been reading it jumping from one page to another, but I haven't found the answers there.

Can I keep results with Strife while I'm Compromised (page 30) if I'm using assistance and my buddies take Strife for me (page 26)?

The text regarding being compromised tells (emphasis mine):

> A   compromised   character’s   vigilance   attribute   (see   page 36)  counts  as  1. Additionally,  when  making  a  check, **a Compromised character cannot keep dice containing strife symbols (to a potential minimum of 0 kept dice)**.

However, the text in Using Assistance reads:

> During **Step 3: Assemble and Roll Dice Pool,** if a char-acter  making  a  check  receives  assistance  from  one  or  more others, the character making the check rolls one additional skill dice per assisting character who has 1 or more ranks of the skill in use, and one additional ring dice per assist-ing character who has 0 ranks in the skill in use. Each player whose character assists must describe how they are helping, and the GM decides if they can contribute.
>
> At  the  GM’s  discretion,  during  **Step  4:  Modify  Rolled Dice**, up to one advantage from one assisting character can be applied.
>
> Then, during **Step 5: Choose Kept Dice,** a character  making  a  check  with  assistance  may  keep  up  to  1  additional die per assisting character.
>
> Finally,  during  **Step  6:  Resolve  Symbols  on  Kept  Dice,**  each  assisting  character  may  **choose  to  suffer  1 strife to negate 1 strife symbol on the check.**

By RAW and due to the order of steps, it seems that a Compromised character cannot keep any dice with Strife symbols, but the last paragraph tells that the symbol is **negated** while being resolved, not ignored. I understand the order being like that so nobody takes Strife negating an unkeeped dice, but if the Strife symbol gets negated, should it be possible to keep it if another person takes the penalty?

Comment: A link to your related question: [Can I offer assistance while compromised?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/168762/can-i-offer-assistance-while-compromised)

Answer (score 1):

I would rule that, as strife symbols are specifically negated in step 6, they should still apply in step 5 when kept dice are chosen. As a result there is no strife for assisting characters to negate